# On the defining relations of integer-valued linear recurrence sequences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $u_n$ be a sequence of integers satisfying a linear recurrence relation
$$u_{n+k}=a_1u_{n+k-1}+a_2u_{n+k-2}+\ldots+a_ku_{n},$$
where the $a_i$ are rational numbers and $k$ is a positive integer. Must the $a_i$ all be integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter-example:
$$
u_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(u_{n+1}+u_n),\quad n\ge0\\
u_0=u_1=2
$$
Every term of this sequence is $2$.

Comment: Thank you for this Jack. I wonder if all counterexamples are so transparently true, or if some such sequences $u_n$ are integer-valued for deep reasons?

Comment: @falang: The sequence $u_n$ satisfies in fact the recurrence $u_{n+1} = u_n$.  From this recurrence, we can get a lot of recurrences of higher order ( multiply the polynomial $(x-1)$ by other poly).  Deeper question still standing.