# Proving some rational numbers are integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $r_1$, $\ldots$, $r_k$ distinct (non-zero) rational numbers, $P_1$, $\ldots$, $P_k \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ non-zero polynomials, such that for every integer $n\ge 0$ the number

$$\sum_{s=1}^k P_s(n) r_s^n$$

is an integer.

Show that all of the numbers $r_1$, $\ldots$, $r_k$ are integers.

$\bf{Notes:}$  This is a particular case of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540700/linear-recurrence-sequence-with-integer-values) I posted  before. The solution I managed to come up with of the general case could be  understood here, even by people not familiar with the rudiments of algebraic number theory. Thus the posting.  I would like to see whether there are any other distinct solutions in this case.  Thank you for your attention!  Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest linking the original question so people see the original thoughts and what direction you aren't looking for :)

Comment: @Alan: Just did that, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Wlog $P_s\in\Bbb Z[x].$

Comment: @Anne Bauval: Yes indeed!